# Facing issue with date function

Tags: oracle, date

I am trying to get the value from dba_scheduler_job_run_details view.
where log_date > (SYSDATE - 5/(24*60)) (i.e. data of last 5 mins)

But it is not providing me with the correct value.

For sample please find the data below:
SQL Query:

```
SELECT SYSDATE, SYSDATE - 5/(24*60),LOG_DATE,TRUNC(LOG_DATE),TO_CHAR(LOG_DATE,'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS')
FROM dba_scheduler_job_run_details 
WHERE LOG_DATE  > (SYSDATE - 5/(24*60))
ORDER BY LOG_DATE DESC;
```

o/p:
image attached[image]

Comment: `HH:MM:SS` - you're displaying month number between hour and seconds.

Comment: You should delete your question when it was just a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `log_date` is `timestamp with timezone` datatype and when you are joining it with date datatype it will lead to two different times when Oracle does an implicit conversion to compare:

```
SQL> SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP, CAST(SYSDATE AS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE) time_with_tz FROM dual;
SYSTIMESTAMP                                                                     TIME_WITH_TZ
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
19-MAR-18 09.57.07.654161 AM -04:00                                              19-MAR-18 09.57.07.000000 AM +05:30
```

So if I execute you query from time zone with offset +5:30 on a server with offset -4:00, Oracle will convert the `SYSDATE - 5/(24*60)` to `sysdate - (9:30 + 0:05)`.

Tell Oracle to convert log_date to date explicitly and then apply the filer of `> (SYSDATE - 5/(24*60)` as follows and you will be fine:

```
SELECT SYSDATE, SYSDATE - 5/(24*60),LOG_DATE,TRUNC(LOG_DATE),TO_CHAR(LOG_DATE,'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS')
FROM dba_scheduler_job_run_details 
WHERE cast(LOG_DATE AS DATE)  > (SYSDATE - 5/(24*60))
ORDER BY LOG_DATE DESC;
```

Update: This query may have performance issue due to following reasons,

> 1) Oracle will convert datatype for each row for column LOG_DATE from
>   timestamp with time zone to date.
>
> 2) The build in index on column LOG_DATE, if any, will not be used due
>   to the CAST function.

Better solution is to convert the sysdate - 5/(24*60) to timestamp with time zone, you must be aware of the timezone of your Oracle server, assuming that the server is located in UTC -4:00, below query should work fine:

```
SELECT SYSDATE, SYSDATE - 5/(24*60),LOG_DATE,TRUNC(LOG_DATE),TO_CHAR(LOG_DATE,'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS')
FROM dba_scheduler_job_run_details 
WHERE LOG_DATE > TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ (to_char(SYSDATE - 5/(24*60), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')  || ' -4:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZH:TZM')
ORDER BY LOG_DATE DESC;
```

Another easier approach as suggested by @mathguy, use INTERVAL function:

```
SELECT SYSDATE, SYSDATE - 5/(24*60),LOG_DATE,TRUNC(LOG_DATE),TO_CHAR(LOG_DATE,'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS')
FROM dba_scheduler_job_run_details 
WHERE LOG_DATE > SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '5' MINUTE
ORDER BY LOG_DATE DESC;
```

Comment: Better (assuming the "timezone" used is the same) - compare LOG_DATE to SYSTIMESTAMP instead of SYSDATE.

Comment: @mathguy thank you for the suggestion, I have updated the answer. Just wondering if there is still a better solution.

Comment: There probably is. I assume `LOG_DATE` is a timestamp in the server time zone. (Sorry, I don't work in the industry; I haven't had the opportunity to work with the scheduler.) If so, then it would be much simpler to test for `LOG_DATE > SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '5' MINUTE`. More generally, `LOG_DATE` should be compared to a function that returns the then-current timestamp with time zone in the same time zone as `LOG_DATE`.